# Firefox default download directory on Xubuntu

Tags: firefox

I am not much familiar with Linux and cannot find the default
directory where the Firefox stores downloaded files. Firefox'
Preferences window says just "downloads" without any path to
the directory.

Answer (score 6):

That should be in your home with the name `Downloads` unless otherwise changed by yourself or another user using your account.

That is a direct reference to Ubuntu default folders and can be changed by editing the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` with a text editor, using for example `leafpad`:

> leafpad ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

This functionality is provided by the package `xdg-user-dirs` installed by default in any Ubuntu flavor.

Answer (score 6):

I found that firefox doesn't actually use the Downloads folder.  Instead it puts everything in `/tmp/mozilla_`*username*`0`

Comment: +1 because this is true, if the user selects the option "Open with:" in the dialog window that appears when downloading a file. This way, Firefox will download a copy in the `/tmp` directory, then allows target application to open the file from there. Hence, a "temporary" default.